# Syntax for hsin query in solr

Tags: lucene, solr

I have created a database and have used dataimport for retrieving the data. I tried out the hsin query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=name:Denver AND _val_:"recip(hsin(0.611941,-1.567437,lat_rad,lng_rad,3963.205),1,1,0)"^100
```

Though there are records that are retrieved, when the value of the radius is drastically reduced (7.205), the ranking for links change. Why is there a change in ranking? The number of records retrieved should have reduced. But this has not happened.

Comment: Official spatial search will be released with Solr 1.5. You could use JTeam's plugin in the meantime: http://www.jteam.nl/news/spatialsolr.html

Answer (score 0):

Solr 3.1 has been released, and for basic geosearch it's much easier to use the higher level spatial support outlined here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch
rather than low level functions like hsin().

Anyway, to more specifically answer your question, a function query matches all documents by default.  Also, the "radius" in the hsin function refers to the radius of the sphere (e.g. the radius of the earth) and not the radius you are searching within.